# FCPython installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to import FCPython on Jupyter notebook:

```
from FCPython import createPitch
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FCPython'
```

when I tried to install it :

```
pip install FCPython
```

I get this error:

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement FCPython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for FCPython

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue when following the Soccermatics tutorial on Expected goal from Friends of Tracking youtube channel.

Solution: FCPython is not a module-package, the code is shared in the github repository where 3xgModel is located.
https://github.com/Friends-of-Tracking-Data-FoTD/SoccermaticsForPython/blob/master/FCPython.py
just put the FCPython.py in the same dir as the code file and run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).